# how to get the ID card in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I created the following tables:

```
create table people (
        ID              varchar(9),
        name            varchar(20),
        CONSTRAINT pk_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

 create table cars (
        license_plate   varchar(9),
        ID              varchar(9),
        CONSTRAINT pk_ID PRIMARY KEY (license_plate)
);

create table accidents (
        code          varchar(9),
        license_plate varchar(9),    
        CONSTRAINT pk_ID PRIMARY KEY (code)
);
```

I inserted the following data:

```
insert into people(ID, name) values('0x1','Louis');
insert into people(ID, name) values('0x2','Alice');
insert into people(ID, name) values('0x3','Peter');

insert into cars(license_plate, ID) values('001','0x1');
insert into cars(license_plate, ID) values('002','0x2');
insert into cars(license_plate, ID) values('003','0x1');
insert into cars(license_plate, ID) values('004','0x3');

insert into accidents(code, license_plate) values('fd1','001');
insert into accidents(code, license_plate) values('fd2','004');
insert into accidents(code, license_plate) values('fd3','002');
```

The question is: **How to select people who don't have had accidents in any of their cars?**

My problem is that when I was trying to use `not in`. Having "Louis" at least one car in the table `accidents`, the query show me "Louis"and should not show "Louis".

My query:

```
select ID from people where ID in (select ID from cars where license_plate not in (select license_plate from accidents));
```

Result:

```
+-----+
| ID  |
+-----+
| 0x1 |
+-----+
```

Comment: Look into `LEFT JOIN`s.

Comment: Post the SELECT query you used, too.

Comment: How do you connect the 3 tables .?. i  don't see relation between the values in cars amd accidents .

Comment: @scaisEdge, thanks i fix it, but the problem continue

Comment: It seems odd but it looks like people > cars on ID / cars > accidents on license_plate.  Yep, that ID in cars is a person.

Comment: @MikeS I update the post but the problem continue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select name from people where ID not in (
  select distinct c.ID from 
    accidents as a inner join cars as c 
    on a.license_plate = c.license_plate 
)
```

Explanation = the sub query will join the cars and accidents, will give you the ID's of all cars who had accidents. On this you can run `not in` query on the people table

Answer (score 1):

I need two subquery

```
        select id from people 
        where id not it 
           (select id form cars where licens_plate not in 
                 (select distintc license_plate  from accidents))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be quite fast:

```
SELECT people.* FROM people
LEFT JOIN cars ON cars.ID = people.ID
LEFT JOIN accidents ON accidents.license_plate = cars.license_plate
WHERE accidents.code IS NULL
GROUP BY people.ID
```